# Border line between Musical Practise & Performance and Audio-Video Production

Tags: discussion

I answered today **[this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11435/looking-for-a-specific-kind-of-interface-external-sound-card)** post, although I think its a big part in musical performance and practise I think it would fit as good in 
[**Audio-Video Production**](https://video.stackexchange.com/).

Should I flag it for migration, or keep it here?

EDIT: same for **[this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11437/how-to-get-the-webcam-to-record-from-guitar-rig-directly)** one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We overlap.  When a question is a good fit here, it should not be migrated, unless (a) it is also a good fit for the other site and (b) the poster has agreed to the migration.

In the case of these two questions I think they are not a very good fit here, and certainly served better by AVP.  (We don't do product searches, and the webcam question is definitely about audio production.)  The second one should have been edited before/after migration IMO, or not migrated and just closed, but Dr. Mayhem knows their site better than I do so I defer to his judgment.

Comment: Ok! thanks for the answer and for putting it were it fits better.